# Rails callbacks not working when create/update/destroy records using background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using **sidekiq-limit_fetch**(with redis) gem for background processing. I have following modal and callbacks

```
class Modal < ApplicationRecord

  # ======== Callbacks ==============================
  after_create :add_activity


  def add_activity
    p 'came here ************'
    p 'came here ************'
    #  Do some operations here  
  end

end
```

I have the job like following

```
class ActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  # TODO - Update goal satisfied people
  def perform(campaign_id)
    Modal.create(data: data)
  end
end
```

I can see some records added in table but after_create  callbacks not called. I thought callbacks will only work when create/update/destroy using model/controller. Am I wright? if yes please suggest me any other way to use jobs with callback.

Comment: callbacks should fire in that case. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Why do you think callbacks aren't fired? Logging on your background workers could be set differently, so you might not  see it in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write service to call or just write your own methods, just use callbacks as little as possible.

Here is my example for service way

services/create_modal_service.rb

```
class CreateModalService
  def self.create(params={})
    modal = Modal.new(params)
    if modal.save
      p 'came here ************'
      p 'came here ************'
      #  Do some operations here
      return true
    else
      return false
    else
  end
end
```

Comment: call like this: CreateModalService.create(data: data)